# angular firestore how to retreive many to many relation data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I coming from RDMS background. I having difficulty to get the relation data through associate collection, here is the collection i got...

```
users collection
- user_1
  - name: abc
  - email: xxxx@example.com
- user_2
  - name: efg
  - email: efg@example.com

groups collection
- group_tech
  - name: tech
- group_finance
  - name: finance

groupUsers collection
- groupUserID
  - groupID: group_tech
  - userID: user_1
```

I want list the user in the tech group, basically i can query like this

```
this.groupUsersCol = this.afs.collection('groupUsers');

this.groupUsersCol.ref.where('groupID', '==', this.params.gid)
  .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
      var employees = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

        // here i only get the user id, how i get the user doc? 
        // Also, i cannot direct call this.afs.doc(...)
        console.log("user", doc.data())
      });
  });
```

there is another way round to solve my problem which modeling my data in this way.

```
users collection
- user_1
  - name: abc
  - email: xxxx@example.com
  - groups: {
      group_tech: true
    }
- user_2
  - name: efg
  - email: efg@example.com
  - groups: []

groups collection
- group_tech
  - name: tech
  - users: {
      user_1: true
    }
- group_finance
  - name: finance
```

the good thing about to store your data in this way, is so convenience to retrieve the data. like...

if you want get all user in the group, you can query in

```
this.afs.collection('users').ref.where('groups.'+group_id, '==', true)
```

same thing to users, get user's groups, absolutely easy. but there is the downside when remove user from the group. you need remove from 2 table.

Please Advice! It would be good by sharing your experience and practice way to do, welcome and thanks you so much!

Comment: Can't you do `this.afs.collection('users').doc(userID)`?

Comment: can't. ends up I found a proper way to do it by using snapshotChanges() turn into observable and process there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the second way, as you mentioned it makes for much better querying and simplifies your security rules. Do note there is a 20k limit on composite-indexes, so don't do it if your users are in thousands of groups.

To solve the downside, instead of handling the "delete" client-side do it server-side with a Cloud Function. Just monitor both users and groups with a Cloud Functions listener, look for changed fields, and if any of the relationships are now `false` delete both sides of the relationship.

Comment: Thanks James for sharing your opinion:)